# How to navigate from one field to another field using Enter Key function in MVC5

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I want to know how to navigate from one field to another field by pressing enter Key in MVC5.

**My View**

```
    <form>
    <fieldset>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
    <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
    @Html.Label("Employee Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control required" })
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="form-group">
    <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text", id = "Date" })
    </div>
    </div>

   <div class="col-sm-3" style="float:left">
   <div class="form-group">
   <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => Model.CustomerName, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CustomerName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.CustomerID)
    </div>
    </div>

   <div class="col-sm-4" id="VisitType">
   <div class="form-group">
   <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
    @Html.Label("Visit Type", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.VisitType, "true", new { id = "" }) Telephone
    </label>
    <label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.VisitType, "false", new { id = "" }) Direct Visit
     </label>
     </div>
     </div>

     <form>
    <fieldset>
```

**My J query**

```
  $("form:not(.filter) :visible:enabled:first").focus();
  $('form > div').keypress(function(e) {
    debugger;
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
  $(this).next().children('div').children(":not(label)").focus();
  } else {
  $("form:not(.filter) :visible:enabled:first").focus();
  }
  }
  });
```

**My Css**

```
div {
margin: 5px 10px;
    }
```

Now this code is working fine in fiddle. But this code is not working in my View. why because I donno where i have to declare this css in my view. Please any one check my code and tell me suggestion for this problem. Before i have css file in script folder.  so i drag and keep that css file in my view. I donno and dont have any css file for this Key Function. So please any one tell me where i have to declare that css coding in my view. And any one suggest me alter method too. I tried my level best to explain my issue. Any one understand and give me solution

Thanks.

Comment: is it a partial view

Comment: No it is not a partial view. it is a main view only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. css**

your view have a layout property like this

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

in the _Layout.cshtml you see in top of file Site.css is included, like so:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css") 
// look at App_Start/BundleConfig.cs to look up which style sheets are included
```

Put your css in the site.css file.

**2. javascript**

in the view add section script for your javascript

```
// view code here ....

@section scripts
{
 // include scripts here
}
```

Comment: I add that jquery code in  between of <script></script> section. Now my doubt is where i have to add this  CSS Code       in view                                                  div {
margin: 5px 10px;
    }

Comment: do you want it to count for whole site?

Comment: Whole site means you asking all views or all fields in particular View??

Comment: Which one lork Whole  views(Customer, City, Area, Visitors views) or all fields (Custmer name, Address, email, phoneno mobile no) in particular view